# Getting user's ip address in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an ip_address field for all my tables that I'd like to popular automatically using the models. How could I set that in the models? I'm guessing I'd have to use the before_save filter for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to use a filter. The ip_address column is a column like every other. Depending on your intention you must find an matching model instance and change its ip_address column or create a new entry including the columnm.

And when you say you have the column in every table its bad style. The ip_address is assigned to a user, not to every single model. I would suggest you to create a new model called `Login` which includes the `ip_address`, `user_id` and the `created_at` and `updated_at` fields. The last one are generated automaticly. Then you can save the ip_address each time the user logs in. Like this in your controller:

```
login=Login.new
login.user=current_user
login.ip_address=request.remote_ip
login.save
```

Comment: The tables are used for by anonymous users (these are visitors who don't create an account). Hence the need to record the ip_address for security reasons in more than 1 table. Your solutions seems to be quite repetitive. What I'd like to know is if it's possible to automatically set it in the models -- without having to manually set it upon form or action processing.

Comment: Its not necassary to login to recognize a user. You can create a model called `Visitor` and write the visitor_id in the session. So you can recognize users without letting them log in and you could associate a `Visit`model (Which has asame fields as the `Login` model I talked about) with the `Visitor` model so you can see when a visitor used which IP-Address.